# How to access back bar button item in universal way under UITests in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

The problem is when I try to access back bar button item because it is presented with:

- `Restaurants` title,
- `Back` title
- **without** title

Like it is on the screens:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Currently I access it like this:

```
let backButton = XCUIApplication().buttons["Restaurants"]
```

but it won't work for other cases. It is not universal way. May I somehow set it accessibilityIdentifier or something else?

Comment: Setting the accessibility identifier is the most robust way as it will give you independence from the label text.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Generally the back button tends to be the first button element in the navigation bar

```
app.navigationBars.buttons.element(boundBy: 0).tap()
```

Comment: You can also add an accessibilityIdentifier to the back button when you're creating it (e.g., `backButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "back"`) and then you just do `app.buttons["back"].tap()`.

Comment: what if there is no back button and another button will be tapped? doesn't work well... need to assign identifier

Answer (score 15):

Based on [Aaron Sofaer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5765054/aaron-sofaer)s comment, you can also set the `accessibilityIdentifier` directly in Interface Builder.

[image]

Comment: Can you do this for the backBarButtonItem though?

Comment: You should be able to do so, when you create it in a storyboard/xib.

Comment: Ah, but not programmatically?

Comment: I don't think, you can access a programmatically created button in the Interface Builder?!

Comment: I mean, if I create the button programmatically and set the accessibilityIdentifier programmatically. I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: What did you do exactly? It should work, as Aaron Sofaer described it in his comment above.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work aqt least as of iOS 11 / Xcode 9. Asserting `button.exists` fails.

Answer (score 10):

Here's how you can do it in **Swift 3**:

```
app.navigationBars.buttons.element(boundBy: 0).tap()
```

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and the accepted one which was posted almost a year earlier?

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-C:**

```
[[app.navigationBars.buttons elementBoundByIndex:0] tap];
```

Comment: Not the best solution because order of the buttons can be changed, and test case will fail. It's better to access the element using accessibilityIdentifier